# How can I reset all Rhythmbox preferences and library information?

Tags: rhythmbox, settings

Background: I cannot figure out how to make Rhythmbox scan ONLY the folder with my music in it. I want to delete all of its settings and start over.

What do I have to do to make Rhythmbox think it's never been run before?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Remove these folders:

- `~/.local/share/rhythmbox`
- `~/.cache/rhythmbox`
- `~/.gconf/apps/rhythmbox`.

You can use your file browser to do this or run this command from the terminal:

```
rm ~/.local/share/rhythmbox/ ~/.cache/rhythmbox/ ~/.gconf/apps/rhythmbox/ -r
```

Answer (score 18):

In recent versions I had to do this to reset gsetting keys (there was no `~/.gconf/apps/rhythmbox`)

```
gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.rhythmbox
gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.rhythmbox.display-page-tree
gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.rhythmbox.library
gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.rhythmbox.player
gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.rhythmbox.plugins
gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.rhythmbox.plugins.iradio
gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.rhythmbox.plugins.lyrics
gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.rhythmbox.plugins.magnatune
gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.rhythmbox.plugins.replaygain
gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.rhythmbox.plugins.visualizer
gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.rhythmbox.podcast
gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.rhythmbox.podcast
gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.rhythmbox.rhythmdb
gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.rhythmbox.sharing
gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.rhythmbox.sources
```

Comment: Missing: `gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.rhythmbox.plugins.alternative_toolbar`

Comment: It's probably easier to open `dconf-editor`, navigate to `org.gnome.rhythmbox` and select the option "Reset view recursively"

Answer (score 2):

All your preferences are stored in `~/.gconf/apps/rhythmbox/` file.

You need to delete this directory, in Nautilus, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to show hidden files, then delete it.

**Warning**: Backup this directory before deleting it.