# Rhythmbox can't organize artist/title from file names

Tags: rhythmbox

I can't seem to get rhythmbox to detect artist, title, and album names from my file system. Currently in preferences, I have folder hierarchy set to artist and file name set to title - this I assumed meant that if I had `~/Music/Billy Joel/We didn't start the fire.mp3` that rhythmbox would detect (and sort) this as the title "We didn't start the fire" by "Billy Joel". I also tried setting `~/Music/Billy Joel` as a library, but that didn't help. I also tried resetting config/prefs/etc per [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7979/how-can-i-reset-all-rhythmbox-preferences-and-library-information), also to no avail. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

check this [answer](https://answers.launchpad.net/rb-fileorganizer/+question/182527) on launchpad. I didn't write here since its very long.

Comment: Sorry this is late - This seems to be for a plugin, I was under the impression that rhythmbox could simply take the structure of my `~/Music` folder and populate artist/title/album/etc. fields accordingly, based on my preferences under Music > Library structure. If not, what are those preferences for?