# Rhythmbox displaying songs from multiple locations

Tags: rhythmbox

I chose my ~/Music directory as my library location in Rhythmbox, but rhythmbox is still displaying songs that are located in other directories. (All the music in my ~/Music folder is in ALAC, but I keep the original flac files in a separate directory for the day my ipod dies and I can completely go with flac)
How can I prevent this? I didn't have this problem on 12.04, but after a clean install of 13.04 I have.

Thanks!

EDIT: 
I noticed "Music" (in Rhythmbox) kan be expanded to "Music" and "Purchased". The former contains only the files from my ~/Music folder as it should. But the "global" Music still show all the files from other folders too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two key areas you should check to resolve this.

### check 1

[image: pic]

In the preferences window you may have a location/multiple locations where rhythmbox is monitoring both the folder(s) set and also sub-folders

[image: pic]

You can change these locations either via the Browser button - or using `dconf-editor`

[dconf-tools](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools)

[image: Install dconf-tools]

### check 2

If you have in the past inadventently imported from another folder location, rhythmbox will remember this.

Thus, you'll need to reset your rhythmbox database - remove the `rhythmdb.xml` file found in `~/.local/share/rhythmbox`

Then reimport all of your music again.

---

Linked question:

- [How can I reset all Rhythmbox preferences and library information?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7979/how-can-i-reset-all-rhythmbox-preferences-and-library-information/271950#271950)

Comment: Resetting my rhythmbox database did the trick. Thanks!