# Rhythmbox does not start after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: rhythmbox, 14.04

When I try to start Rhythmbox its window remains only for few seconds then it disappears and I get "An internal Ubuntu error" message. Even if I try to open an MP3 file I see the same scenario.

Tried to reinstall it (twice :D)

Started from command line:

```
(rhythmbox:9164): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_css_provider_load_from_path: assertion 'path != NULL' failed

(rhythmbox:9164): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: object SoupServer 0x2afc3e0 finalized while still in-construction

(rhythmbox:9164): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: Custom constructor for class SoupServer returned NULL (which is invalid). Please use GInitable instead.
Unable to open ~/.mtpz-data for reading, MTPZ disabled.Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

*UPDATE*

Just found a bug report to launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rhythmbox/+bug/1299245 , but the problem does not seem to be fixed

Comment: Start it from command line and check if it throws an error. If so copy it into your question please.

Comment: @Rinzwind I updated the question, as I see there is no "~/.mtpz-data" file or directory

Comment: @micnic - there is not "fix" because the OP in the bug report never supplies a stack-trace thus it become unreproducible.  Try resetting rhythmbox as per here and if it works, you'll need to reimport/re-do all of your music/playlists/ratings again. http://askubuntu.com/questions/7979/how-can-i-reset-all-rhythmbox-preferences-and-library-information

Comment: thank you @fossfreedom , I removed those folders and it worked , your comment should be an answer, post it as an answer and I'll accept it as the best one ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Trouble-shooting

Trouble-shooting rhythmbox issues can be a bit of a trial and error.

These are the areas you should consider.

### Cleaning up plugins settings

Sometimes a rogue plugin (internal or external) could be the cause of rhythmbox crashes.

Cleaning up the gsettings database for the various plugins can work:

```
gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.rhythmbox.plugins
```

### Cleaning up locally installed plugins

Occasionally, compilation issues occur if you install external plugins manually - removing these plugins and reinstalling will resolve this.

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/rhythmbox/plugins
```

### Cleaning up all rhythmbox settings

Occasionally, a corruption can occur in other rhythmbox settings.   Using [Dima's answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/271950/14356) will resolve this.

### last resort

If the above does not work then the problem is likely to be due to corruption in the rhythmbox database and related files itself. Using [Alvin's answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/7982/14356) will resolve this.

Note though - if you use the last resort method you'll need to reimport/re-do all of your music/playlists/ratings again.

Answer (score 0):

Disable replay gain in plugins as it has issues with VBR tracks. I found on 12.04 it wasn't a issue but 14.04 started giving me problems with this. What I figured out it could be a gstreamer issue.