# after shutting down ubuntu playlists in rhythm box dont work

Tags: rhythmbox

I created playlists in rhythm box. After shutting down ubuntu and restarting when the playlists are clicked saved songs are not appearing.

Also all the files are coming under 'podcasts' in shuffled manner under the heading 'missing files'.

Now I have installed 'restricted extras' from the software center. Still the problem persists.

I have imported mp3 songs and assigned them to playlists and successfully played them. Problem arises when I restart the system. After that songs are not appearing in the window when I click on 'music' or on playlists. How can I install this package? I am new to ubuntu.

Comment: have you tried resetting rhythmbox? http://askubuntu.com/questions/7979/how-can-i-reset-all-rhythmbox-preferences-and-library-information

Comment: How to reset rhythmbox?

Comment: That link I gave you describes how you do a reset

Comment: I did the reset. Problem is still there.

Comment: Rajesh - please add to your question exactly how you are importing the songs and adding to playlists.  What version of rhythmbox?  What version of ubuntu?  If you can add links to screenshots that would be easier to understand what you are doing.

Comment: ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, rhythmbox 3.0.2    I will give you the steps.                     click on 'music', click on 'import', select the folder containing songs. click on open,  files appear in a window. click on'import listed tracks', files appear in bottom window. select songs and drag and drop over playlist name.